# How to find all regex match in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

This might be too simple to find on web but I got problem with finding the answer.

I get string as http response text that contain substrings I want to grab all one by one to further process. Its relative URL.

for example:

```
var string = "div classimage a hrefstring1.png img idEMIC00001 he19.56mm wi69.85mm srcstring1.png  separated by some html         div classimage a hrefstring2.png srcstring2.png div separated by some html many such relative urls";
var re = new RegExp("[a-z]{5,10}[0-9].png");
var match = re.exec(string)
WScript.Echo (match);
```

This gives first match. I want to get all collection one by one. I am using Jscript. I am new to javascript.

After the answer I tried this.

```
var string = "div classimage a hrefstring1.png img idEMIC00001 he19.56mm wi69.85mm srcstring1.png  separated by some html         div classimage a hrefstring2.png srcstring2.png div separated by some html many such relative urls";
var re = new RegExp("[a-z]{5,10}[0-9].png", "g");
var match = re.exec(string)
WScript.Echo (match);
```

But no luck.

Comment: Use the `g` modifier to get back an array.

Comment: `.png` should probably be `\.png`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `'g'` for a global search and `match` to get all matches:-

```js
var string = "div classimage a hrefstring1.png img idEMIC00001 he19.56mm wi69.85mm srcstring1.png  separated by some html         div classimage a hrefstring2.png srcstring2.png div separated by some html many such relative urls";

var re = new RegExp("[a-z]{5,10}[0-9].png", 'g');

var matches = string.match(re);

for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++){
    console.log(matches[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is what I Wanted.

Comment: Tried but said, You can no accept in 2 minutes. Wait buddy.

Answer (score 3):

This should fix your problem :

`var re = new RegExp("[a-z]{5,10}[0-9].png", "g");`

The "g" stands for global, it'll match all occurrences in your string

Comment: This is right answer, but please add some expanation for the original poster.

Comment: I blindly tried replacing line suggested by you but no luck. Might be the problem is jscript. Is there anything else I need to change. As This is my just first hand at javascript after basic learning please see if anything else is wrong in my script.

Comment: @Rahul Use `string.match(re)` instead of `re.exec(string)`

Comment: This is giving me a string that is comma separated. But good. I already had next question comming how to get all match as single string. As I asked specifically get matches one by one I think form this question BG101's answer is exact what I wanted.

Comment: @Rahul Actually it's giving you an array, BG101 added a loop to display results one by one

Answer (score 1):

just make it

```
var match = string.match(re)
```

instead of

```
var match = re.exec(string);
```

rest of the code seems to be fine.